# $A$ open, $S$ closed. Can $S \setminus A$ be compact?

Tags: general-topology

Given sets $A$ open, $S$ closed

Can the set $S \setminus A$ be compact, even if $A$ nor $S$ is compact?

Comment: Yes, consider $S = [0,\infty)$ and $A=(1,\infty)$ over $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $S=\mathbb R, A=\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$

I really don't know how you got the idea to ask that. You can take any topological space $S$ (well, choose it to be Hausdorff and not compact, i.e. any unbounded metric space) and choose $A$ to be a complement of a compact set.

Comment: It's probably because of the wording. One could think "compactness implies compactness" and here we see that it doesn't need to.